# url referral difference between internet explorer and google chrome browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i am referring a page using response.redirect in my web page, it is working with Internet Explorer. However, the same is not working when I browse my website using Google Chrome. Even when I am trying to print the values using response.write it is not working in Google Chrome. (I am using asp.net with c#)

Comment: what does your response.redirect look like? a code example will help.

Comment: Chrome does not like certain characters in the `Location` header (happened to me about a year ago) - FF, Opera, IE and Safari did not have a problem. Check your redirection strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since Response.Redirect is server side, it shouldn't matter what browser you're using.

```
Response.Redirect("~/My/New/Page.aspx"); // Where the tilde (~) is the application root
```

or if you're redirecting outside the application, you need to use the FQDN

```
Response.Redirect("http://example.com");
```